# Spark (Scala) conditionally write JSON to multiple dynamic output locations

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I have a problem to solve where data comes in as JSON from kinesis like below:

```
{
 datatype: "datatype_1"
 id : "id_1"
 data : {...}
}
```

All records in the stream then need to go through a lookup function with datatype and id passed as arguments to find a unique group of locations to write the items to in JSON.

i.e.

```
def get_locations(id: String, datatype: String): Array[String] = //custom logic here
```

where the resultant array would look like

```
 [ "s3:///example_bucket/example_folder_1", "s3:///example_bucket2/example_folder_2"]
```

My question is how do I most efficiently group records coming off the stream by datatype and id and write to the various s3 locations. I was hoping to do something like below:

```
        sparkSession.readStream.format("kinesis")
          .option("streamName", kinesis_stream_name)
          .option("initialPosition", "latest")
          .option("region", aws_region)
          .load()
          //more transforms
          .select(
            col("datatype"),
            col("id"),
            col("data")
          )

// Not sure how I can do what's below

//          .write.partitionBy("id", "datatype")
//          .format("json")
//          .option("compression","gzip")
//          .save(get_locations("id","datatype")) //saving to all locations in result array
```

Comment: having bucket_id/folder_date/is good for you ?

Comment: Unfortunately the location has to be based on runtime configuration (lookup from dynamodb) so I can't have fixed locations or locations based on the data itself

Comment: so you are getting the confs  as in input , my idea is to create a bucket with name containing either id or the dataType then a folder containing either id or datatype => you store your file (partitionned on those two parameters ) in your bucket /folder !! if it is good for you tell me

Comment: it cannot be fixed and needs to be configurable. For example with id: "id_1" , datatype: "dt_1" today the dynamoDB entry may be

 [ "s3:///example_bucket/example_folder_1", "s3:///example_bucket2/example_folder_2"]

but tomorrow (without code changes) it could change to

 [ "s3:///example_bucket3/example_folder_4", "s3:///example_bucket4/example_folder_3"]

The location is completely outside of my (or the codes) control (with the only known being that it is an s3 bucket)

Comment: ok listen give me a concrete example  dataType and a concreate id an an example of path name in that case , I have a quesion 2: how you get (read) the id and the dataType you mentioned dynamDB as a source before , would you explain that to me please

Comment: As a concrete example for id = "ff985c55-3ff7-4ecb-aacb-b545585e2ec4" and datatype = "users" we would pass both of those into the get_locations function and it would look up the existing table "ff985c55-3ff7-4ecb-aacb-b545585e2ec4-catalogue" with an entry row having column id "users". One of the other columns on this row contains write locations which in this example would be:
[s3:///d58afa18-11e8-4a30-b953-857baefd36da-group-bucket/archiveData/user_data/, s3:///d58afa18-11e8-4a30-b953-857baefd36da-group-bucket/stagingData/user_data/]

These buckets and folders already exist.

Comment: as I understood your paths already exist in the json file that you will take it as input

Answer (score 0):

***I do advise you to create the bucket in the code in the runtime as a best practice, you can use the node.js aws S3 API or your runtime language API***

As you said in your comment you are getting the parameters from your runtime.
However as an answer to your question here is a function that creates a bucket containing the id in its name (you can change it to the format that you like ) then in that bucket you will have a lot of files based on the partition of the dataframe while saving:

```
import java.util
import com.amazonaws.regions.Regions
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.{AmazonS3, AmazonS3ClientBuilder}

def get_locations(id: String, datatype: String) = {

//you can configure the default region to the adequat region 
//of course 
      val s3: AmazonS3 = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard.withRegion(Regions.DEFAULT_REGION).build

object CreateBucket {
  def getBucket(bucket_name: String): Bucket = {
          var named_bucket = null.asInstanceOf[Bucket]
          val buckets: util.List[Bucket] = s3.listBuckets
          import scala.collection.JavaConversions._
          for (b <- buckets) {
            if (b.getName.equals(bucket_name)) named_bucket = b
          }
          named_bucket
        }

        def createBucket(bucket_name: String): Bucket = {
          var b = null.asInstanceOf[Bucket]
          if (s3.doesBucketExistV2(bucket_name)) {
            System.out.format("Bucket %s already exists.\n", bucket_name)
            b = getBucket(bucket_name)
          }
          else try b = s3.createBucket(bucket_name)
          catch {
            case e: AmazonS3Exception =>
              System.err.println(e.getErrorMessage)
          }
          b
        }
      }


      //change your bucket name here if
      //you like
      val bucket_name = "bucket_" + id

      var my_bucket = null.asInstanceOf[Bucket]
      if (s3.doesBucketExistV2(bucket_name)) {
        System.out.format("Bucket %s already exists.\n", bucket_name)
        my_bucket = CreateBucket.getBucket(bucket_name)
      }
      else try my_bucket = s3.createBucket(bucket_name)
      catch {
        case e: AmazonS3Exception =>
          System.err.println(e.getErrorMessage)
      }
      my_bucket
    }

    //I don't know how you will get those parameters
    

    var id = " "
    var datatype = " "
    df.write.partitionBy("id", "dataType")
      .format("json")
      .option("compression", "gzip")
      .save(get_locations(id, datatype).toString)
```

Don't forget to add the dependecies in maven or in build.sbt with the version that you have already in aws (sdk) :

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
    <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-s3</artifactId>
    <version>1.11.979</version>
 </dependency>
```